# BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe when trying to p.stdin.write()

Tags: python, ffmpeg, rtmp

I'm trying to write video frames to an RTMP stream using FFMPEG and Python subsystem. It seems to work well when I run the script on Windows, but encounter the error `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe` when run it on my server/Ubuntu device.

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
rtmp_url = "rtmp://..."

path = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

# gather video info to ffmpeg
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))


# command and params for ffmpeg
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
           '-r', '30',
           '-i', '-',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-preset', 'slow',
           '-threads', '0',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp_url]

# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)


while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("frame read failed")
        break

    # write to pipe
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
```

The error doesn't provide much, and I'm also quite inexperience working with Ubuntu. So any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: RTMP uses TCP protocol, and it's required that the "listener side" be opened before starting FFmpeg. For debugging add `'-report'` argument, and check the **log file**. In case the log file shows error: "Cannot open connection", that means that no one is waiting for accepting the TCP connection. You may have to install and execute [rtsp-simple-server](https://github.com/aler9/mediamtx), and use port `1935`. Note that I never tried it on Ubuntu Server. Also try without `shell=True`. In case there is still an issue, please post the content of the log file.

Comment: So it is the `shell=True` part of the code. With it, the log file will also not be generated. Maybe it is only needed when running on Windows. After removing it, it runs quite well. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ok so it works for a bit, then the error Conversion failed! What be the reason?

Comment: The code looks correct, I don't think I can help you...